# How can i collapse all objects in JSON view in firefox

Tags: javascript, html, json, firefox, firefox-addon

I am using http://jsonview.com/ to view the josn in my browser.

By default it shows all objects expand. Is there any way to collapse , expand all with one click or by default.

I have 100 objects and its very time consuming to click on + or - icon

Answer (score 1):

After skimming [the code](https://github.com/bhollis/jsonview/), there apparently isn't such a functionality, so [you may ask the author to add it](https://github.com/bhollis/jsonview/issues).

Answer (score 1):

You can also paste this in your console

```
`(function(nodes){ for(index in nodes) { node = nodes[index]; if (node.hasOwnProperty('className')) node.className = 'hoverable collapsed' } })($$('.hoverable'))`
```

It should do the trick!